# How can I write a program to find the index of a character in a sentence?

Tags: java

I need to be able to read a desired character from the keyboard and locate its index. Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q12Test
{public static void main(String args[])

   {int index;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter desired character to find its index: ");
    index = kb.nextInt();

    String quote = ("Our greatest weakness lies in giving up. The most certain way to succeed is always to try just one more time. Thomas A. Edison");

        for (int i = 0 ; i<quote.length() ; i++)
        {    if (quote.charAt(i) == ' ')
               System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does your attempt not work as expected?  When you debug it, where does it fail?

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering? I mean, that can't be solved by replacing the hardcoded space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading index but never using it in the search logic...

I would change the type of index for a char instead AND compare the index with the **char at index i**

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char index;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter desired character to find its index: ");
    index = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
    final String quote = ("Our greatest weakness lies in giving up. The most certain way to succeed is always to try just one more time. Thomas A. Edison");
    for (int i = 0; i < quote.length(); i++) {
        if (quote.charAt(i) == index) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to replace the hard-coded space (`' '`) in your `if` statement with the input you get from the user.

Additionally, it just so happens that the `String` class in java has an [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) method that will accomplish exactly what you're trying to do with the `for` loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter desired character to find its index: ");
    char charToFind = in.nextLine().charAt(0);

    String quote = "Our greatest weakness lies in giving up...";
    System.out.println(quote.indexOf(charToFind)); // -1 if not found
}
```